# Issue with 'this' as it pointing to window in angular2 on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

I am working on Angular2 project with Typescript and found a weird problem. My code is working in Chrome but not working in IE11. Find the code below.

```
this.loaderService.setFullLoader(true, "Generating PDF");
this.pdfGenerationStarted = true;
setTimeout(() => {
  kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(this.reviewAndSubmitNativeForm.nativeElement), {
    paperSize: "A4",
    scale: 0.5
  }).then((group) => {
    kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "CAR Request.pdf");
    this.pdfGenerationStarted = false;
    this.loaderService.setFullLoader(false, "Generating PDF");
  });
}, 100);
```

"this" in line 4th pointing to the current object in chrome but pointing to window in IE11

Comment: Not sure how your build process is but [IE11](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11) has no support for es6 functionalities including arrow functions.Are you using [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) ?

Comment: Hey suraj, Thanks for your quick reply. I am using arrow function in other functions also and they are working fine in IE11 also. But inside setTimeout they are not working in IE11 even after using es6-shim.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No. Only this points to window.

Comment: I found the problem. If i hover on this in IE11 debugger it shows me Window but if i print it using console.log(this) it point to current object. Cheers.

Comment: so there is no problem.. :)

Comment: Where do you have this code? Where is it called from?